# Find all regions (lat, long, radius) that contain a point

Tags: postgis, distance, latitude-longitude, st-distance

A `Region` has a latitude, longitude (`GEOMETRY('POINT')`) and a radius.

Using postgis, how can I query all `Region`s where the distance from `pointParam` and `region.point` is less than or equal to `region.radius`?

```
SELECT *
FROM region
ORDER BY region.origin <-> my_location
WHERE (region.origin <-> my_location) <= region.radius // <--- This is where I don't know what to put
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the (pseudo) query that worked for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM regions
WHERE ST_DWithin("origin", ST_MakePoint(lat, long), max, false) = true AND ST_Distance("origin", ST_MakePoint(lat, long), false) - radius <= 0 
ORDER BY distance ASC 
LIMIT 5;
```

I figured out how to do the actual distance query; use the built in gis distance function and just subtracted radius from the distance. If that value is less than or equal to 0, then it should not be returned.